# Is it possible to run a js or python script from a .js or .py file when a button in Flutter is pressed? (Not Flutter Web)

Tags: javascript, python, flutter, dart

I want to make a flutter app that, when a button is pressed, it runs a python or a js script that I made and is saved in a .js or a .py file. Essentially, I want to run a .js or a .py file when a button in Flutter is pressed. Is that possible? And if yes, how can it be done? I am making a desktop application that has to work offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it requires Python and JS interpreters to be installed on the device. A way to ensure this is to ship them together with your app, although this will take a lot of extra space. From your app, you just launch the interpreter as a subprocess, for example `python3 your_script.py`

If your script is hardcoded and not changed later by the app, you can also turn it into a standalone executable, using a tool such as *py2exe*. But this is basically the same thing, the interpreter just ends up included in your script.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of launching the interpreter as a subprocess? Im fairly new to this whole thing.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not familiar with Dart/Flutter, so I can't point you at a code example, you'll have to google that. But overall, "launching a subprocess" should be easy, it's essentially just "running an external program"

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Consider marking my answer as accepted, if you end up using this technique

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using API, you make API in django or flask backend which run the python script you want after you make a request to your API via clicking the flutter button

Comment: And this requires no internet?

Comment: this method only works using [cloud or local] web server

Comment: @elkhayyat, what would be the point of a local web server here? Why not execute the script directly?